# Call Tuple Values using string as pointer

Tags: python, string, variables, tuples

```
import string
count = 0 # Button press Counter
Letter = string.ascii_lowercase[count]
print(Letter) # returns string, a

class Colours:
   a = (255,0,0) #Tuple to be called

print(Colours.Letter[0:3]) #returns Attribute Error: class Colours has no attribute 'Letter'
```

'''How can i use string 'Letter' to call tuple 'a'?'''

Comment: Please clarify your question.  You cannot *call* a tuple; you call a function.  If you're trying to *access* the tuple, how does `Letter` relate to that access?  Your program logic is not at all obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You want the builtin `getattr` function:

```
>>> getattr(Colours, Letter)
(255, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access attributes by their name (as a string) using

```
getattr(Colours, Letter)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

> `getattr(object, name[, default])`
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `getattr()`[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function it's designed for that

```
class Colours:
   a = (255,0,0) #Tuple to be called

print(getattr(Colours, 'a'))
```